# Issue updating css-transformed div's height (FlexBox, Sass)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a div whose text has been transformed via css. Now, I am trying to set the height (along the axis of the words) based on the height of a neighboring column.

The div has been transformed via css in this way:

```
.skills-bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  p {
    font-family: Bitter, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

The html markup:

```
   <div class="container__row">
      <div class="container__col-sm-12 container__col-md-8 container__col-md-8">
        <ul class="skills-content">
          <li>
            <div class="list-title">Python</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list-title">Java</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list-title">C</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="list-title">Prolog</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="container__col-sm-12 container__col-md-4 container__col-md-4 skills-bar">
        <p>Programming</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

All the other css classes (using sass), the ones I think are relevant are highlighted using comments, but maybe i'm missing something that's coming from somewhere else:

```
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";

body {
  text-align: center;
  font: 1em/1.5 Georgia, serif;
  color: #333;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Bitter, Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 2.25em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Bitter, Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

li {
  margin: 10px 5px 15px 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

//RELEVANT to html markup in post
//site container with set max width
$grid__bp-md: 768;
$grid__bp-lg: 992;
$grid__cols: 12;
//sass map to define breakpoints
$map-grid-props: ('-sm':0, '-md': $grid__bp-md, '-lg' : $grid__bp-lg);
//mixin to dynamically create media query  for each breakpoint
@mixin create-mq($breakpoint) {
  @if($breakpoint == 0) {
    @content;
  } @else {
    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint *1px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
@mixin create-col-classes($modifier, $grid__cols, $breakpoint) {
  @include create-mq($breakpoint) {
    //class to set up columns for all screen sizes - mobile first
    @for $i from 1 through $grid__cols {
      &__col#{$modifier}-#{$i} {
        flex-basis: (100 / ($grid__cols / $i)) * 1%;
      }
    }
  }
}

.container {
  max-width: $grid__bp-md * 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  //attribute to override max width
  &--fluid {
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  //attribute to position row's child elements. remove overflow with wrap and 100% width for nesting
  &__row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }
  @each $modifier, $breakpoint in $map-grid-props {
    @include create-col-classes($modifier, $grid__cols, $breakpoint);
  }
}

//header
.header {
  padding: 10em 0 14em;

  h1 {
    font-style: italic;
  }
}

.footer {
  p {
    color: #777;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }
}

.header,
.footer {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.content,
.footer {
  padding: 4em 0 6em;
}

.content {
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;

  h1 {
    color: #ea4c89;
  }

  p {
    font-size: .85em;
    color: #aaa;
  }
}

.avatar {
  @include box-shadow(0 0 0px 3px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #ccc, 0 4px 6px #333);
  @include border-radius(50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.list-date {
  font-family: Bitter, Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: .85em;
  color: grey;
}

.list-title {
  font-family: Bitter, Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.list-company {
  font-family: Bitter, Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-size: .85em;
  color: black;
}

.list-align-left {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20px 0 64px 0;
}
//RELEVANT to html markup in post
.skills-bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  p {
    font-family: Bitter, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    color: black;
  }
}

.fit-to-content {
  display: inline;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

#prog-bar {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  border-right: 15px solid  #B8B8B8;
  width: 20em;
}

#front-bar {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border-right: 15px solid #D0D0D0;
  width: 20em;
}

#design-bar {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-right: 15px solid #E0E0E0;
  width: 20em;
}

#gis-bar {
  background-color:     #F0F0F0;
  border-right: 15px solid #F8F8F8;
  width: 20em;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  background-color: grey;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

/* Container around content */
.text-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

/* The circles on the timeline */
.text-container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #FF9F55;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Place the container to the left */
.left {
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Place the container to the right */
.right {
  left: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
.right::after {
  left: -5px;
}
/* The actual content */
.timeline-content {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

// Shared styles
.icon-facebook:before,
.icon-twitter:before,
.icon-instagram:before,
.icon-google-plus:before,
.icon-youtube:before,
.icon-dribbble:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?ebzao9');
  src:  url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?ebzao9#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?ebzao9') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?ebzao9') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?ebzao9#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

// Shared styles
.icon-facebook:before,
.icon-twitter:before,
.icon-instagram:before,
.icon-google-plus:before,
.icon-youtube:before,
.icon-dribbble:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

//Individual styles
.icon-email:before {
  content: "\ea84";
}
.icon-instagram:before {
  content: "\ea92";
}
.icon-twitter:before {
  content: "\ea96";
}
.icon-skype:before {
  content: "\eac5";
}
.icon-linkedin:before {
  content: "\eac9";
}

.social {
  margin:2em 0;
  font-family: Noto, sans-serif;

  li {
    position: relative;
    @include inline-block();
    margin: .5em;
    @include transition(all .15s ease);
    border-radius: 6px;

    &:hover {
      @include scale(1.25);
      color: white;
    }

    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      width: 2em;
      margin-left: -1em;
      top: 1.5em;
      left: 50%;
    }

    a {
      display: block;
      color: inherit;
      padding: 2.5em 1em 1em;
      width: 6em;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
  }
}

/* Twitter */
.icon-twitter {color: #00a0d1}
.icon-twitter:hover {background:#00a0d1;
box-radius:6px;}
/* Instagram */
.icon-instagram {color: #634d40}
.icon-instagram:hover {background: #634d40}
/* Facebook */
.icon-skype {color: #00aff0}
.icon-skype:hover {background: #00aff0}
/* Twitter */
.icon-linkedin {color: #0077B5}
.icon-linkedin:hover {background: #0077B5}
/* Twitter */
.icon-email {color: #c71610}
.icon-email:hover {background: #c71610}
```

And finally, the jquery to loop over the elements of skills-content class to corresponding elements of the skills-bar class. Some background on this: it seems as though the transformed div's height is calculated before the transform, so I am working around it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419199/vertically-stacking-transformed-text-using-sass-css-and-flexbox/51419882#51419882) way, using jquery.

Intuitively, I am trying to set the height attribute of the transformed div using the calculated height of the unordered list. However, I am noticing some strange behavior--the height of the transformed div seems to be producing a width and not a height. I tried to update the width attribute instead (not pictured in code below), but this did not solve my issue :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var skillsContent = $(".skills-content");
  var skills = $(".skills-bar");
  $.each(skills, function(j, titlediv) {
      console.log(titlediv);
      console.log(skillsContent[j]);
      var dimensions = skillsContent[j].getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(dimensions);
      $(this).css("height", dimensions.height+"px"); //this line is where I attempted to modify the width instead, but it still isn't working
  });
});
```

Using chrome dev tools, this is what I get when identifying the ul element (to be measured) and the div element (to be adjusted). *Note, that measuring ul element is arbitrary, as the real issue is the way the attribute is dynamically set (i think). FYI, I eventually want to get the container div height--I've measured the ul in this case just to highlight a strange behavior that I will describe in my next point.

[image]
[image]

I don't know if this helps at all, but when I counter-intuitively set the width attribute to the calculated ul height, this is what happens (the new value seems to correspond to the ul's parent div height for some reason I can't currently see):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var skillsContent = $(".skills-content");
  var skills = $(".skills-bar");
  $.each(skills, function(j, titlediv) {
      console.log(titlediv);
      console.log(skillsContent[j]);
      var dimensions = skillsContent[j].getBoundingClientRect();
      console.log(dimensions);
      $(this).css("width", dimensions.height+"px"); //this line is where I attempted to modify the width instead, but it still isn't working. Setting max-height doesn't change anything either
  });
});
```

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

Testing out the simplified jquery code from below, I added some print statements because I still felt unsure about why I'm unable to set the "width" (visually the height) of the transformed div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.skills-bar').each( function() {
    console.log("got here");
    $(this).css( 'width', $(this).parent().innerHeight() + 'px' );
    console.log($(this).parent().innerHeight());
    console.log($(this).width());
  });
});
```

Print statements are still puzzling:

```
got here
graphic_rendering.js:16 166
graphic_rendering.js:17 124
graphic_rendering.js:14 got here
graphic_rendering.js:16 205
graphic_rendering.js:17 124
graphic_rendering.js:14 got here
graphic_rendering.js:16 166
graphic_rendering.js:17 124
graphic_rendering.js:14 got here
graphic_rendering.js:16 49
graphic_rendering.js:17 124
```

What I am noticing is that the "width" (visual height) of the div grows as the width of the measured div increases.

Updated css :

```
.skills-bar {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: left top;
  //position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width:100%;
  p {
    font-family: Bitter, Georgia, sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The positioning of the element is rendered first based on the un-transformed dimensions, then the transform including rotation and translation is applied, so the post transformation "height" on the screen is actually the width. This is true even when the css is modified based on the javascript.

The percentage in the top, left, right, or bottom position rules is a percent of the parent container but the percent in the transform translate rules is a percent of the element itself.

Understanding the rendering order may help you troubleshoot, but I have included a simpler jQuery loop and 3 examples in the snippet with styles that you could copy. One with no padding, one with parent padding, and one with parent padding outside of an inner container.

```js
$('.skills-bar').each( function() {
  $( this).css( 'width', $( this ).parent().innerHeight() + 'px' );
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.skills-content {
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
}

.skills-content li {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.skills-bar {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate( -90deg ) translateY( -100% );
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
}

.container:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding: 2em;
  background: yellow;
}

.container:nth-of-type(3) {
  padding: 2em;
  background: green;
}

.inner-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="skills-content">
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">Python</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">Java</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">C</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">Prolog</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="skills-bar">
    <p>Programming</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="skills-content">
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">Python</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">Java</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">C</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="list-title">Prolog</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="skills-bar">
    <p>Programming</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <ul class="skills-content">
      <li>
        <div class="list-title">Python</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="list-title">Java</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="list-title">C</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="list-title">Prolog</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="skills-bar">
      <p>Programming</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I figured it was something related to the height being the width. I'm okay with that--I'm still confused, then, why the width is not the height though. Also, I'm testing out your function and css and will respond soon.